# Is there a way to deactivate fonts via terminal or similar?

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I have the problem that I cannot activate a font in the *Typeface* app because the font was apparently activated before. It stops with an error about duplicate fonts, which seems legit since I can see the font being active in the system_profiler.

The problem is: That font is not shown as active in *Typeface* (so I cannot deactivate it here), nor is shown at all in macos font book app (all kinds of 'deactivate fonts' guides rely on that). In *system_profiler* I cannot see any button/dialog to deactivate a font.

Now I wonder: What's the "macos system" way to deactivate a font? I had no luck with some googling and looking around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Ok, a better search keyword would have been "clear font cache". It is a bit of a nuke option but it worked in the end.

I found it here: https://gist.github.com/jaredhowland/2da83f0cc0fbb1ac523f
This pdf from extensis with best practices is linked in that gist: https://doc.extensis.com/Font-Management-in-OSX-Best-Practices-Guide.pdf

In short: To clear the font caches, close all applications, start a terminal and enter:
`sudo atsutil databases -remove`. Then restart the Mac.

In the pdf it says:

> 1. Close all applications. (Important!)
> 2. Start Terminal (located in the **Utilities** folder; press Command-Shift-U to open this folder).
> 3. Type `sudo atsutil databases -remove` and press Return.
> 4. Type your password at the prompt (no characters will echo back to the screen).
> 5. When the process is complete, type exit to end your command line session, choose **File** > **Quit** to exit Terminal, then restart your
>    Macintosh.